# Separate the nodes and avoid overlapping in tree graph in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a responsive horizontal tree layout. The link: d3.js https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-field-vsc6m. My child nodes are getting overlapped.

How do I separate the nodes with a minimal distance and avoid the overlap?

[image]. The code can be found in the above code sandbox link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and found out that you are using a constant value for radius(45).

I have edited your code and saved the logic for dynamic radius. I am not sure if you will 
be able to save it or not. So, I am putting the logic of radius here as well.

I would also suggest you to not use labels inside the nodes for better visual experience and use tooltip for that. Just a suggestion and its upto you.

Please let me know if it resolves your issue.

```js
node.append("circle").attr("r", function(d, i) {
  const padding = 5
  // find siblings of a  node
  let siblings = (d.parent && d.parent.children) || null;
  // find minimum radius based on their x values so they don't overlap.
  let radius =
    siblings && siblings.length > 1 ?
    (siblings[1].x - siblings[0].x - padding) / 2 :
    45;
  return radius;
});
```

[image]